# How to define a function with a parameter one string and return a new string which has the middle char repeated as much as the length of the str

Tags: python-3.x

Define a function called repeat_middle which receives as parameter one string (with at least one character), and it should return a new string which will have the middle character/s in the string repeated as many times as the length of the input (original) string.

Notice that if the original string has an odd number of characters there is only one middle character. If, on the other hand, if the original string has an even number of characters then there will be two middle characters, and both have to be repeated (see the example).

Additionally, if there is only one middle character, then the string should be surrounded by 1 exclamation sign in each extreme . If , on the other hand, the original string has two middle characters then the  returned string should have two exclamation signs at each extreme.

As an example, the following code fragment:

print (repeat_middle("abMNcd"))

should produce the output:

!!MNMNMNMNMNMN!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: looks awfully like a homework problem!

Comment: No, they're just practice problems that I am finding online for my exam coming up soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def repeat_middle(string):

    l = len(string)

    if l % 2 == 0:

        return "!!{}!!".format(string[int(l / 2 - .5) : int(l / 2 + 1.5)] * l)

    else:

        return "{}".format(string[int(l / 2)] * l)

odd  = "ham"
even = "spam"

print("Original odd length string: {}".format(odd))
print("Returned string: {}".format(repeat_middle(odd)))    
print("")
print("Original even length string: {}".format(even))
print("Returned string: {}".format(repeat_middle(even)))
```

Where the sample output is:

```
Original even length string: spam
Returned string: !!papapapa!!

Original odd length string: ham
Returned string: aaa
```

You will find that `print(repeat_middle("abMNcd"))` does indeed output `!!MNMNMNMNMNMN!!`.